# How to turn off Fiddler breakpoints

Tags: http, fiddler

I am using Fiddler v4.4.1.1 beta.

I once activated automatic before the request breakpoint. Now I have disabled it back, but Fiddler continues to break. I do not know what to do.

Observe:

[image]

Notice, the breakpoints are disabled and the same tells the status line - there is no breakpoint icon there.

Yet, the breakpoint is still active:

[image]

I cannot use Fiddler any more.

I have issued the bpafter, bps, bpv, bpm and bpu commands without any arguments to clear any possible breakpoint. I have never thought I would ever call Fiddler like this, but it continues to break.

Comment: In this screenshot, you can see that the Filters are active by the checkmark in the tab's icon. If you're ever curious in the future about why a given breakpoint was hit, right-click the Session and choose "Properties." In the window, you'll see the Flag's value like so: X-BREAKREQUEST: BreakXHR

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found it.

There is another place where breakpoints are exposed - the filter tab, which I often use, but never knew it controls breakpoints as well:

[image]

The confusing part is that I have never touched this option - only used the host filter part. Apparently, setting an auto breakpoint in the rules menu now sets this flag too, silently. But it is not cleared back when I disable the breakpoint, which is a terrible UI experience.

Comment: Sorry, but no, that is not correct. The *only* way that checkbox gets checked is if you specifically check it. No other setting impacts it.

Comment: I am sorry, but I know what I was doing. Today is the first time I have ever seen this checkbox. Turned breakpoints on in the rules menu - yes, ticked this checkbox - never. Fiddler is absolutely great (thank you very much for it), but as any software it has bugs and this is probably one of them.

Comment: No one would suggest that Fiddler is bug-free, but with millions of users and 9 years of maintenance, I'm confident in saying that this isn't one of them. :-)

Comment: Maybe it was accidentally set by shortcut key.

Comment: Thank you!  upvoted.  using v5.0.20182.28034 for .NET 4.6.1 and had same problem with Fiddler filter set to "Break request on POST".

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me like a charm.

### **Some useful info about breakpoints in Fiddler:**

You can use the ***QuickExec (ALT+Q)*** to enable/disable breakpoints using commands like: ***bpafter, bpv, bpu*** 
Also one of the killer features is the QuickExec command ***"g"* or *"go"*** that resumes all the breakpointed sessions (this one is available in the UI using the **"Go"** button).

See [Fiddler QuickExec documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/QuickExec) for more info.